C# - Form shows differently at runtime compared with design time
Why is this happening?
Form at design-time compared with runtime:

When I try to move to another place, the same problem occurs.
Any object that I try move to the another place, in build showing in different positions.
I try change scale and monitor resolution but nothing works

I realize that your first language is likely not English, but I dint understand your question. You show two images that (without looking too carefully) appear the same. Your description really doesn't help much. I can't tell what you are describing. Can you try to make it clearer

The runtime version of the form (the left) has controls that have moved compared with the design-time equivalent (the right).

By any chance, do you use the Anchor properties for those controls, and is your form derived from another custom form? If so, this is a known issue. Try use docking instead of anchoring to prevent your controls from wandering around.

The form layout is different during run-time. Do you use localization of forms? There will be more than one form resouce file, with localization culture in name, storying different layout there. As always, try to reproduce the issue using [mcve], then someone here can have a close look.

See docs: Adjusting the size and scale of Windows Forms (also see Automatic Scaling and High DPI Support), Walkthrough: Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using a TableLayoutPanel (also see other Walkthroughs)

Walkthrough: Lay out controls with padding, margins, and the AutoSize property

Have you checked the value of the Anchor property for each component? Keep them the same and try again. Can you describe your problem with more detail, such as example codes and what you do with the runtime?
